# Calling a method from the container class in binding

Tags: c#, wpf

I effectively have -

```
<UserControl ...>
<Grid>
    <TreeView Name="nTree">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="NodeType" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image x:Name="icon" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

NodeType is a type returned by an underlying library. I would like to set the icon images source based on the name provided - however I can't modify NodeType to add a getter.

So ideally what I would like is the icon image source to be bound to a function on the UserControl class which receives the Name and returns an ImageSource.

i.e.

```
public partial class Panel : UserControl
{
    public Panel(NodeType n)
    {
        nTree.Items.add(n);
    }

    public ImageSource GetIcon(string name)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This feels like it should be possible but i'm struggling to work it out. Assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't bind to methods,  you need to convert the method to a property

you can do this in several ways

the easiest would be to have: (though this should be on your VM not your V)

```
public ImageSource Icon
{
    ...
}
```

or you can use a value converter:(the best fit for what you are descibing)

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        GetImageLogic
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("One way only");
    }
}
```

the 3rd option would be to use an [CommandBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308(v=vs.110).aspx) :

then bind to the command

```
CommandBinding OpenCmdBinding = new CommandBinding(
    ApplicationCommands.Open,
    OpenCmdExecuted,
    OpenCmdCanExecute);

this.CommandBindings.Add(OpenCmdBinding);

void OpenCmdExecuted(object target, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String command, targetobj;
    command = ((RoutedCommand)e.Command).Name;
    targetobj = ((FrameworkElement)target).Name;
    MessageBox.Show("The " + command +  " command has been invoked on target object " + targetobj);

}

void OpenCmdCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - i've managed to get it working with a value converter. Its not ideal but it gets the job done in a not-horrendously messy fashion.